# display errors of the type net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

Following the angular 2 documentation and specifically https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html with code example in plunkr [here](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/server-communication/ts/plnkr.html) - I was trying to simulate the error scenario for broken server link (so to call).

```
GET http://localhost:3002/heroes net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
scheduleTask    @   zone.js:1990
ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask   @   zone.js:384
onScheduleTask  @   zone.js:274
```

However in the template html `{{errorMessage}}` I'm getting `0 - {"isTrusted":true}`. How do I gather the error message  `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` ?

Note that one need to add `import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';` to the service so as to avoid the error - `TypeError: Observable_1.Observable.throw is not a function` which would otherwise be encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/3eUdPsoHOuAlgVJHoOw6?p=preview).

In addition to missing `import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';` as you have already stated, in the example you have provided there was an issue with parsing the error response object to json. In the case of successful response, `res` response object contains `_body` property, which is of type `Object`, and thus you can convert it with `.json()`. However, in the case of unsuccessful response, `error` response object contains `_body` property that contains HTML, where you can't use the `.json()` method. You can check all of this in your console by inspecting `error` response object.

You don't really have to convert the `error` response object with `.json()` as you already have status code and status text information in there. You can check it in the Plunker link I've posted.